# Understanding Key space

Tags: key-size

I've looked at a few previous posts on this site but I'm still struggling with the concept of keyspace. Specifically I'm following a coursera course but I think it's probably too advanced for me as I'm failing to understand some numbers.

In the course it talks about a substitution cypher in an alphabet of 26 letters. There is then a question

> What is the size of key space in the substitution cipher
>   assuming 26 letters?

The answer is 26! (I get this bit) but the instructor then says this is roughly equivalent to 2^88 which I don't get as the numbers don't seem close to me at all.

Furthermore it talks about the enigma machine and how a 4 rotor machine which would have the following

> ## keys = 26^4 = 2^18
>
> This is equating to 26^4 combinations (4 rotors with 26 keys - again I get this (though should it not be 26!^4?) but then I don't get how this gives a key space of 2^18 . I think it's the equality signs throwing me off as I'm thinking it's 'equal to' as opposed to it 'equates to or resolves to'.

I just don't get these numbers if I'm honest.

Can someone break it down in it's simplest terms for me? As I say, based on this evidence I think the course might be beyond me mathematically, but I really want to understand at least this part now I've gone through it!

Comment: Hint for the first part: What is $\log_2(26!)?$ Similar for the second part.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're not getting.

You understand that the keyspace for a simple substitution cipher is $26!$; do you understand that $26! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times ... \times 24 \times 25 \times 26$, correct?

So, we have $26! = 403291461126605635584000000$, correct?

We also have $2^{88} = 309485009821345068724781056$, correct?

Would you agree that these are "roughly" the same (where roughly in this case means within 30%)?

> keys = 26^4 = 2^18

What might be confusing you is the equal sign; obviously $26^4 = 456976$ is not exactly $2^{18} = 262144$; I believe the idea the author is trying to convey is that they're close, well, at least close enough for his analysis.  I'd personally use $\approx$ here...

> (though should it not be 26!^4?)

Actually, for Engima, 26 is correct; each rotor can be set in one of 26 positions; hence each rotor can do one of 26 specific permutations; it can't do an arbitrary 26! permutation.

Comment: I think it really is the equals sign confusing me especially The second example as I really don't consider them to be roughly equal. But then I don't get why the key Space for the enigma machine is smaller than then substitution cypher when the enigma has the four rotors and was designed to be more complex

Comment: @TommyBs: it has a smaller keyspace because it defines fewer transforms from plaintext to ciphertext; with their Enigma model, you could set each dial to one of 26 settings an that's it (actually, real Engima machines had a bunch of other things you could do, such as select which rotor went where); in contrast, a substitution cipher does define an impressively large number of potential transforms.  That's also a useful example for people who think large key spaces ensure security...